# Fit all points added to map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just created a dynamic google maps with Wordpress.

Now I'm looking for a way, after I spawn all points on the google maps, to re-center/zoom the map to fit all spawned points into the container with, let's say, a 10% margin on every side.

I searched the API and didn't find something that looked like it could help.

Is there a way to do it or do I need a snippet?

PS: I'm using the API V3 with Javascript (populating the map via PHP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to loop an array of markers and extend the bounds. This example assumes a markers[] variable that you've populated previously with every marker added to the map.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
    markerIndex = 0;
for (markerIndex; markerIndex < markers.length; markerIndex++) {
    var marker = this.markers[markerIndex];
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need a list of coordinates, for example:

```
var LatLngList = array(new google.maps.LatLng(52.537,-2.061), new google.maps.LatLng(52.564,-2.017));
```

Instance of `LatLngBounds`:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Extend each LatLng to this instance:

```
for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
  bounds.extend(LatLngList[i]);
}
```

And `fitBounds()`:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```